# Python Coercing Mixed Factor Levels to String

Tags: python, categories, categorical-data

I have a certain column in a Pandas Dataframe that have the following unique factor levels:

```
My_Factor_Levels = [9.0, 0, 6.0, '9', '6', 9, 6, 'DE', '3U', '9.0', '6Z', '6.0', '9.', '6.', '3B', '1U', '2Z', '68', '6B']
```

Note that there are ten separate values in My_factor_Levels (9.0, 6.0, '9', '6', 9, 6, '9.0', '6.0', '9.', '6.') that represent values from two different factor levels - '9' and '6'.  How can I coerce these values to conform to one unique grouping (preferably in string format)?  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try casting values as either `int` or `float` and then converting to a set (all unique values in the iterable):

```py
My_Factor_Levels = [9.0, 0, 6.0, '9', '6', 9, 6, 'DE', '3U', '9.0', '6Z', '6.0', '9.', '6.', '3B', '1U', '2Z', '68', '6B']

def safe_convert(x):
    try:
        return str(float(x))
    except:
        return x

coerced = set([safe_convert(x) for x in My_Factor_Levels])
```

```py
>>> coerced
{'0.0', '1U', '2Z', '3B', '3U', '6.0', '68.0', '6B', '6Z', '9.0', 'DE'}
```

If you would prefer the final `coerced` result to be a list, simply do `list(set(...))` instead.